# How to implement an addressable FIFO queue?

Tags: data-structures

I'm currently looking for a data structure with all O(1) operations

- insert(K, V): Insert a value at the end of the queue.
- remove_key(K): Remove the value from the queue corresponding to the provided key.
- remove_head(): Remove the value from the front of the queue (the oldest one).

The only reasonably easy to implement thing I can think of is using a doubly linked list as the primary data structure, and keeping pointers to the list nodes in a hash table, which would get the desired asymptotic behavior, however this might not be the most efficient option in actual runtime.

I found "addressable priority queues" in the literature, but they are rather complicated (and maybe even more expensive) data structures, so I was wondering if someone has a better suggestion. It seems no one implemented something like this for Rust so far, which is why I'm hoping it doesn't get too complicated.

Comment: Your idea of using a separate hash table is the standard implementation. An addressable priority queue uses the same concept. If you're trying to implement your priority queue with a binary heap, then it gets complicated. But if you use something like a Pairing heap, it's not any more complicated than your double-linked list idea.

Comment: A bit late but if anyone still looks for a working solution, I wrote the following crate a while ago (not actively maintaing it anymore): https://crates.io/crates/addressable_queue

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `pub struct VecDeque<T>` and use `pop_front()` instead of `remove_head()`.

See the doc: [VecDeque](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html)

Comment: The problem is `remove_key(K)`. I could use a (growable) ring buffer like `VecDeque` but then `remove_key(K)` would be `O(n)` since I would have to iterate all items in the worst case. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it, because otherwise I might even use a FIFO queue and just mark elements as deleted and make remove_head() skip the deleted elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Greyvend/8474814094175559fed215dfd80df603) I implemented an **Addressable Binary Heap** in Python, no third-party dependencies.